# PHP Combine Class Definition & Class Method Call into one line

Tags: php, class, object

I've been using lines like this in my code for a long time:

```
        $preferences = new preferences();
        $preferences->updatePreferences('prefer_CM_or_IN',$joinPrefer_CM_or_IN);
```

In situations when an object is only used for one method is it possible to combine this into one line of code? Or is it better to leave as one?

Just interested.

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [version 5.4](http://3v4l.org/Jp7ap) you can use:

```
$v = (new A())->b();
```

(Don't miss the brackets around the constructor call)

Or in your case:

```
(new preferences())
  ->updatePreferences('prefer_CM_or_IN',$joinPrefer_CM_or_IN);
```

---

In former versions of PHP there wasn't a syntax feature than could be used to chain a constructor and a method call

Comment: thx for teaching me. greatly appreciated :) - will tick when time limit is up

Comment: just tested it and it works great... really appreciated... will use this ongoing when only one method call is required... cheers :)

Comment: Yes and no. A static call isn't the same as an object method. It will have unwanted side effects if you do useing it "ongoing". maybe it was a "bad" advice (I think now) .. Check my update ;)

Comment: unfortunately in 5.4 `($instance = new A())->b();` doesn't work :( So there's no way of capturing that new instance... unless method `b` returns it via `return $this;` see http://codepad.viper-7.com/0bTB7B

Comment: Do you mean its best if I go back to the 2 lines in my initial question? happy to if you think its safer...

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.3, the best you can do is this:

```
function preferences()
{
  return new preferences;
}

preferences()->updatePreferences('prefer_CM_or_IN',$joinPrefer_CM_or_IN);
```

not that I recommend doing it...